# Marionette - triggering actions from controllers

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to understand all the logic behind routers and controllers in Marionette. As you can see below each example is using different approach to handle the triggering actions mechanism,so it's really hard to decide which approach should I be using.

1. example - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410059/suggested-bootstrap-boilerplate-sample-for-backbone-marionette-application/11598371#11598371) - this one renders the views from the APpController
2. example - [link](https://github.com/jsoverson/todomvc/tree/master/labs/dependency-examples/backbone_marionette_require) - uses Marionette.EventAggregator
3. example - [link](https://github.com/cbroome/marionette_example/tree/master/js) - uses the App instance to trigger all the actions.

It's also worth mentioning that most of them are 2-3 years old hence I'm asking my self whether or not use them in my app.

I have created a basic `Marionette.AppRouter` and `Marionette.Controlle`r inside my `Marionette.Application` instance. All the defined routes in my `AppRouter` module are working correctly. So I wanted to go further and update one of my views once the "#home" route is fired. But I was unable to do so, as after reading all the docs, it was still not clear to me how to update all my views from the `AppController`?

1. Should I use EventAggregator for all the communication between `AppController` and  `Marionette.Applicaiton` ?
2. Should I define my `LayoutView` including `ItemViews`..etc in my `AppController` ?
3. Or should I just pass an instance of my App to `AppController`?

I' would be really glad if someone pointed me to a simple, **up-to-date** (AMD) example.

Comment: I'd go with the third example, but I'm partial since I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

The newest way is [Backbone.Radio](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio). It will be the default event manager in the next big version of Marionette. You can [shim it](https://gist.github.com/jmeas/7992474cdb1c5672d88b) into the latest version and use it today.

Personally I decided on using Radio together with a custom made router. There are conflicting opinions on how to organize everything but I kept both radio and the router outside of the scope of Marionette.Application (window.radio, window.router, window.app). It works well and can be another viable option.